# enter inside curly braces does not indent

Tags: vimrc

When I create a curly braces and press enter inside it I get this behavious

```
{|} -> enter key

{
|}
```

Now how do I get vim to do this

```
{|} -> enter key

{
    |
}
```

my vimrc brief

```
filetype plugin indent on
set lazyredraw
set smartcase
set smartindent
set ignorecase
set nocompatible
set number
set numberwidth=1
set autoindent
set backspace=2
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set shellslash
set clipboard=unnamed
set smarttab
```

Comment: For what filetype? Please also show the output of the various indent settings.

Comment: it happens for all filetypes. I have notice it in C and CSS. That's the only indent settings I have rest of all are just mappings

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: as of now I am using `iab { {<CR>}<Esc>ko` to have the kind of behaviour I want. Do you need to know any other thing? VS Code does what I described in my question. So I thought why not it is possible with vim.

Comment: I've asked because there are several plugins providing that sort of behavior. I'll post an answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

While mappings and abbreviations in insert mode should work, Vim has a large number of plugins -- some of them may have proven and largely tested solutions since what you are asking is probably a common feature.

Some of the keywords you could try searching plugins for are [complete](https://vimawesome.com/?q=complete) and [braces](https://vimawesome.com/?q=braces).
This last search, for example, brings [vim-c-cr](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-c-cr):

> Finish braces, brackets and parentheses with ctrl+enter in vim
>
> A very simple and small (33 lines of vimscript) plugin that maps
>   ctrl+enter () and ctrl+c ( for terminal-vim users) in
>   insert mode to finish braces ({}), brackets ([]) and parentheses (())
>   for you and puts your cursor tabbed over on a blank line between them.

But you certainly can find more plugins with similar behavior.

Comment: I will take a look at the plugins you mentioned. Thank you very much

Comment: @neelabalan I hope it helps

Comment: It did. I am now using the vim-c-cr plugin you mentioned. Thank you